# Nested block all side spacing

Tags: html, css

I need a cross browser solution using css without JS or jQuery.
So i have two divs:

```
<div class="block1">
  <div class="block2">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

I need block2 to be full width of block1. I need spacing in every side 15px for block2. It must be responsive layout width and height. block1 must be 100% page width and height.
What i see. Something wrong with block2 margins. I didn't get 15px spacing all side in block2. I have problem with bottom side for now.
block1 = background: red;
block2 = background: black;
First i think that it is an easy task, but for now i didn't find solution.
What i have tried:
Html

```
<body class="body">
    <div class="block1">
        <div class="block2">
            content
        </div>        
    </div>      
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
}
.body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;        
}

.block1 {
    width: 100%;
    background:red;     
    height: 100%;      
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.block2 {
    background: #000000;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the problem here???i've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/cwxefmt4/) for you..

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/79tywL8j/?

Comment: This fiddle make screen to be 100% +15 px. So I get scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are 2 examples for you:

**1.** if you dont mind it not supporting IE 8 and below, you can use css [CALC()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) to calculate the min-height of the inner block: `min-height: calc(100% - 30px);` (30 being the top+bottom margins)

```css
html, body  {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.block1 {
    width: 100%;
    background:red;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.block2 {
    background: #000000;
    min-height: calc(100% - 30px);
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
    <div class="block2">content</div>
</div>
```

**2.** a solution that should be supported in IE 8, is this:

```css
html, body  {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.block1 {
    width: 100%;
    background:red;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.block2 {
    background: #000000;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
    <div class="block2">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the last one can help for cross browser solution. Thanks, it works. Also, can you explain please, how it get works. I see block2 absolute but don't see relative block. For now i don't understand how works second example.

Comment: Also, can you explain please, how it get works. I see block2 absolute but don't see relative block. For now i don't understand how works second example.

Comment: since both blocks need to fill the entire window, block 2 doesnt need to be relative to block 1. block one fills the entire page, and block 2 is positioned absolutely to the page as well.